# Take certain parts from string, then use it to create one string variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a variable that's a string from a list
The list is just the alphabet (Don't ask why, it just has to for the program)

```
passwords = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
```

Basically, I used to have a variable that took 4 random letters from it to create one string that looked like this:

```
correctPassword = random.sample(passwords,4)
```

What I need is 4 specific characters from the list to create the same kind of string variable, the word "STOP".

An answer to this would be greatly appreciated, I'm trying to recreate the hacking minigame from Fallout, if any of you know what that is, thanks!

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far to solve this. Explain using your code what issues you are facing.

Comment: Can you try and word it a little clearer?

Comment: Since the letters are in order, cant you just use an index for the indexes of s,t,o,p?

Comment: please tell me you didn't type out passwords and did `passwords = list(string.ascii_uppercase)`

Comment: he is not using passwords for security purposes, i think he is using this as a check to see if a player enters  predetermined password.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but...
To create a string variable equal to "STOP":

```
x = "STOP"
```

The line of code

```
correctPassword = random.sample(passwords,4)
```

doesn't create a string variable but a list of strings 4 items long, each item being a 1-character string.  Using x as defined above, the expression `x == correctPassword` will always be false.

To consolidate those into a single string:

```
correctPasswordAsString = ''.join(correctPassword)
```

A comparison `x == correctPasswordAsString` will be true if correctPasswordAsString is "STOP", false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for create a string variable from list:

```
import random
passwords = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
correctPassword = random.sample(passwords,4)
result = ""
result = result.join(correctPassword)
print(result)
```

and get something like:`STOP`

The Python [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method is a string method. It merges a list of objects into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the variable as the following:

`correctPassword = ["S", "T", "O", "P"]`

Or, you can use the indexes of the letters:

`correctPassword = [passwords[18], passwords[19], passwords[14], passwords[15]]`